# Aligning numbered elements with custom spacing

Tags: spacing, numbering, vertical-alignment

I am trying to achieve the following result:

```
1.   Section 1
     Some text here
1.1  Subsection 1
     Some text here
     (a)   Some text here
     (b)   Some text here
           (i)   Some text here 
           (ii)  Some text here
2.   Section 2
     Some text here
```

Here is what I have now:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label*=\bf{\arabic*}]\itemsep6pt
\item
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label*={\arabic*}]
\item
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]\itemsep6pt
\item
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]\itemsep6pt
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label*={\arabic*.}]\itemsep6pt
\setcounter{enumi}{10}
\item
```

But this doesn't give me the proper alignment and spacing. Moreover if I want to make another list I need to set the counter manually, what is not that convenient. Any advice on how to do this in a more convenient way?

Comment: This code isn't compilable at all. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have mentioned what I want to achieve on the top of my post. I agree that this is not the best attempt for the proper implementation. Could you suggest anything better?

Comment: @code6reaker: Don't mix the use of [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) and [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). Use one *or* the other, but not *both*.

Comment: @code6reaker: Posting a non-functioning code where not even `\section` etc. occur does not clearify the request. I would start to provide better examples.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the feedback! I'm new to the LaTeX, but I'll try better to explain myself in the further posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following achieves your requested layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[30pt][l]{\csname the#1\endcsname}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\alph*),align=left}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\roman*),align=left}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example

\section{First section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tellus dolor, 
euismod venenatis enim a, dapibus scelerisque neque. Duis dolor sem, bibendum 
in diam ac, iaculis ornare neque. Integer et congue sapien. Praesent diam 
nunc, ultrices quis lobortis quis, tincidunt lacinia diam. Nulla at nulla dui. 
Mauris vitae venenatis odio.

\subsection{First subsection}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tellus dolor, 
euismod venenatis enim a, dapibus scelerisque neque. Duis dolor sem, bibendum 
in diam ac, iaculis ornare neque. Integer et congue sapien. Praesent diam 
nunc, ultrices quis lobortis quis, tincidunt lacinia diam. Nulla at nulla dui. 
Mauris vitae venenatis odio.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tellus dolor, 
  euismod venenatis enim a, dapibus scelerisque neque. Duis dolor sem, bibendum 
  in diam ac, iaculis ornare neque.

  \item
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tellus dolor, 
  euismod venenatis enim a, dapibus scelerisque neque. Duis dolor sem, bibendum 
  in diam ac, iaculis ornare neque.

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tellus dolor, 
    euismod venenatis enim a, dapibus scelerisque neque. Duis dolor sem, bibendum 
    in diam ac, iaculis ornare neque.

    \item
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tellus dolor, 
    euismod venenatis enim a, dapibus scelerisque neque. Duis dolor sem, bibendum 
    in diam ac, iaculis ornare neque.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Second subsection}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tellus dolor, 
euismod venenatis enim a, dapibus scelerisque neque. Duis dolor sem, bibendum 
in diam ac, iaculis ornare neque. Integer et congue sapien. Praesent diam 
nunc, ultrices quis lobortis quis, tincidunt lacinia diam. Nulla at nulla dui. 
Mauris vitae venenatis odio.

\section{Second section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tellus dolor, 
euismod venenatis enim a, dapibus scelerisque neque. Duis dolor sem, bibendum 
in diam ac, iaculis ornare neque. Integer et congue sapien. Praesent diam 
nunc, ultrices quis lobortis quis, tincidunt lacinia diam. Nulla at nulla dui. 
Mauris vitae venenatis odio.

\end{document}
```

The section number is printed in the margin via an adjustment to `\@seccntformat` (which usually just prints the number followed by a `1em` space - `\quad`). Adjust `30pt` to suit your needs.

First- and second-level `enumerate` environments have their labels printed with a `left` alignment using the key-value interface provided by [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

Comment: Thanks @Werner! Although your solution clashes over all of these packages included further in my document: \usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{hyperref} Is there any way to get it working with these packages?

Comment: @code6reaker: I have no problem compiling my example when adding the listed packages in your comment. If the problem persist, I'd suggest creating a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem and include that in your original post as an edit. Otherwise it would be difficult to guess what's going on at your end...

Comment: I have tried just to compile the solution you've provided and it gives me "Missing \endcsname inserted. Undefined control sequence". I am using ShareLaTeX.

Comment: @code6reaker: Did you remove the `enumerate` package from your preamble? Could you provide a link to a document on ShareLaTeX that I can look at?

Comment: Sure I can share this thing. What's your email?

Comment: @code6reaker: You should be able to share a ShareLaTeX document via a link right here... in the comments. As mentioned, make sure this is minimal and doesn't include your whole thesis, or whatever you're doing.

Comment: You should be able to view this link: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5678620b37710f497cb067a7

Comment: @code6reaker: Your minimal example is not really minimal, as it adds a landscape page that is not really necessary, including `geometry` changes. Moreover, it doesn't use my suggested `\section` ... `\begin{enumerate}` ... `\end{enumerate}` construction. You still have content using your old manual formatting of the list environments *and* using *both* [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) as well as [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

Comment: I've updated the document to look more minimal with applying your solution. Unfortunately I get "cannot compile error".

Comment: @code6reaker: ShareLaTeX currently still runs under TeX Live 2014, so add `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` to your preamble. [`fixltx2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) has been incorporated into the LaTeX2e kernel since 2015. That's why I couldn't replicate your problem - I'm running on the latest kernel, but ShareLaTeX doesn't.

Comment: adding the package, you've mentioned, definitely solved the issue. Thanks for your help and assistance on figuring out what's wrong on my side! For anyone having similar problem and working with ShareLaTeX I will keep the solution public https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5678620b37710f497cb067a7.